# Any chance I can use websocket to connnect to MS Teams so I can get real-time message in the channel of MS Teams?

Tags: .net, websocket, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, real-time-updates

Is there any way that I can monitor a channel of MS Teams so that I can get all real-time messages posted in the channel?I used to use websocket connection to meet that kind of requirement,but this time I can't find any websocket related information in the **Graph API** documentation or anywhere.So where should I begin?

Comment: Not sure about web sockets, but you can create a subscription to a team channel resource and then get near real time notifications (HTTP request) whenever a new message is sent in that channel, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: I notice that ```NotificationUrl``` is set in the sample code.I wonder what url should I set if I want to craft a winform application to create a subscription on each  channel of teams.

Comment: The url needs to be publicly available from the internet. This isn't going to work in a Windows Forms app.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks a lot.So I guess I can't use channel subscription on my app.Is there any other way that I can get real-time message?

Comment: How about using the change feed and then start polling?

Comment: @Stephan any sample code about chnage feed?It's just I am new to the Graph API.

Comment: I'm not sure if also supported with chatMessages, but this link show you how it works with messages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-messages

Comment: so if I want to know if there is any change in the channel I have to send a request with last request's delta link?If so,it's very tricky about how often should I send a new request.I don't think it's a good way to get real-time message.

Comment: Since you’re building a Windows Forms app, you have no way the get real time messages. This why you don’t have to build a check if it returns new messages. You could also setup a backend, subscribe to notifications, send SignalR message to all clients.